# Parsing Wiki Markup with PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a text file with Wiki markup. Example:

```
[[April]]

April is the fourth month of the year. It has 30 days. The name April comes from that Latin word aperire which means "to open". This probably refers to growing plants in spring. April begins on the same day of week as July in all years and also January in leap years.

April's flower is the Sweet Pea. Its birthstone is the diamond. The meaning of the diamond is innocence.

== April in poetry ==

Poets use April to mean the end of winter. For example: April showers bring May flowers.

== Events in April ==

[[August]]

August is the eighth month of the year in the Gregorian calendar, coming between July and September. It has 31 days, the same number of days as the previous month, July, and is named after Roman Emperor Augustus Caesar.

== The Month ==

This month was first called Sextilis in Latin, because it was the sixth month in the old Roman calendar. The Roman calendar began in March about 735 BC with Romulus. October was the eighth month. August was the eighth month when January or February were added to the start of the year by King Numa Pompilius about 700 BC. Or, when those two months were moved from the end to the beginning of the year by the decemvirs about 450 BC (Roman writers disagree). In 153 BC January 1 was determined as the beginning of the year.

August is named for Augustus Caesar who became Roman consul in this month.  The month has 31 days because Julius Caesar added two days when he created the Julian calendar in 45 BC. August is after July and before September.

August, in either hemisphere, is the seasonal equivalent of February in the other. In the Northern hemisphere it is a summer month and it is a winter month in the Southern hemisphere. In a common year, no other month begins on the same day of the week as August, though in leap years, February starts on the same day as August. August always ends on the same day of the week as November.

August's flower is the Gladiolus with the birthstone being peridot. The astrological signs for August are Leo (July 24 - August 22) and Virgo (August 23 - September 23).

== August observances ==

=== Fixed observances and events ===

=== Moveable and Monthlong events ===

== Selection of Historical Events ==

== References ==
```

April and August are both wiki articles.  I managed to pull titles with the following:

```
$fh = fopen("wiki2.txt", "r");
if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        preg_match_all('#\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]#',$line,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach($matches as $m) {
            echo $m[0]."<br />";
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

However, I want to be able to pull the text inside the articles too.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do (regex or other solution) to pull the article data?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "pull the article data"? The text is all there? What's your actual goal? If you want to convert Wiki markup to HTML, there are existing solutions, http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki, and we have [lots of similar questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+parse+wiki+markup) on this topic.

Comment: I want to split the Article titles (which is being stored in $m[0]), from the article text (haven't found a way to match that yet).

In the end, I want to have these select article titles and article content in separate variables, which I can insert into my MySQL database.

Comment: MediaWiki (the software that runs Wikipedia) is written in php and is open source. You can get the parser form their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this (plus, wiki markup is no more Regex-ready than HTML.)

Why not just do:

```
$HeaderNumber = 0;
$Document[$HeaderNumber]['Title'] = "Default";
while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        if (strpos('[[', $line) > -1 && strpos(']]', $line) > -1){
            $Document[$HeaderNumber]['Text'] = implode($Document[$HeaderNumber]['Lines'], "\n");
            unset($Document[$HeaderNumber]['Lines']);
            $HeaderNumber++;
            $line = str_replace(array("[[","]]"), "", $line);
            $Document[$HeaderNumber]['Title'] = $line;
            continue;
        }

        $Document[$HeaderNumber]['Lines'][] = $line;

    }
}
```

This creates an array, numerically indexed, each with a Title and a Text field containing exactly what you'd expect from the name. You could further process the text into HTML using [the Text_Wiki module](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki) from the pear library.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for. However, the code inside the if statement never seems to get executed. I checked the output of strpos('[[',$line), and got nothing. Is that an issue with how $line is outputting? :\

Comment: I managed to get it working using different code, but I am still using your strpos code. Problem with that is that strpos only checks for a single character, not 2.  Is there a way to check for both brackets?

Comment: Hm, if that's not working it's probably a type coercion problem (which  strpos has been at the heart of before, sadly.) It's definitely checking for both - notice that i've done a test for each inside the if.

Comment: Aha, yes - duh, of course it isn't work. strpos is returning 0 for the '[[' test because the character is in position 0. Edited the example, should work now. :) (I also fixed the missing bracket.)